# Jasmine test, not catching "<method> is not a function" error

Tags: angular, jasmine

In my Angular 7 component, `ngOnInit` is calling a method (`getRecurrence`) on a service.  For testing, I am mocking the service, but the mock is missing the method.  (So, the component code is correct, but the test mocks are wrong)

Component source snippet:

```
async ngOnInit() {
  try {
    var results = await Promise.all([
      this.lookupService.getRecurrence(),
      ...
    }
  }
```

When I run the test, I get the expected error message `TypeError: this.lookupService.getRecurrence is not a function` in the log file, but Jasmine and Karma report that the test passes.

**Edited:** The Jasmine test is mostly the standard one created from `ng g c ...`.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule],
    providers: [
      { provide: LookupService, useClass: MockLookupService }
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Since `ngOnInit` is async, I tried adding either `async()` or `fakeAsync()` to the `beforeEach` that creates the component and the test case that verifies it was created, to no avail.

Any suggestions on how to get Jasmine and Karma to catch the error and report failure?

**Edited:** I implemented Bill Cheng's suggestions, still no luck.  I added console log message to the tests (and replaced the `await Promise.all()` with `await this.lookupService.getRecurrence()`), and this is what I get.

ngOnInit source snippet:

```
async ngOnInit() {
  console.log('ngOnInit')
  try {
    console.log('Before getRecurrence')
    this.recurrences = await this.lookupService.getRecurrence();
    console.log('After getRecurrence')
    ...
  }
}
```

Test code:

```
it('should create', async() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  console.log('should create before whenStable')
  await fixture.whenStable();
  console.log('should create after whenStable')
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Console log results:

```
ngOnInit
context.js:245 Before getRecurrence
context.js:245 TypeError: this.lookupService.getRecurrence is not a function
    [stack trace deleted]
context.js:245 should create before whenStable
context.js:245 should create after whenStable
```

It looks to me like someplace the TypeError is being handled and eaten, so as far as Jasmine is concerned there was no exception...

Comment: Can you update your question to include the relevant code? What does the test look like?

Comment: 1. Try to move `fixture.detectChanges();` to it(...)   2. remove the async in beforeEach   3. use `await fixture.whenStable();` after detectChanges... this should solve your problem

Comment: @BillCheng No joy, still not catching the error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was staring me in the face, I just needed to post a little more of the code.

```
async ngOnInit() {
  try {
    ...
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I'm eating the error so that the unit test doesn't see it.  /.\

Comment: not a good idea to catch and swallow an error to pass a test. Does you user know you have and error?